# splitting Android project into modules?

Tags: android

I followed this ["tutorial"](http://saulmm.github.io/2015/02/02/A-useful-stack-on-android-1,-architecture/) here and loved the idea of splitting up an Android project into modules. But now I stumble upon problems I wouldn't have otherwise, e.g. that I can't use SQLiteOpenHelper in the model-module as it's plain Java and not Android.

Is there a way to use Android-Classes (e.g. SQLiteOpenHelper) there nevertheless or is it recommended not to split up the app at all?

Comment: Not sure to get you... A DataBaseHelper normally resides on its own Class  (a single Java file).

Comment: How about importing SQLiteOpenHelper on your java class..

Comment: I can't import it in the non-Android-module as the class doesn't exist there

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - I have to subclass ```SQLiteOpenHelper``` but I don't find a way to use/import it in a non-Android project

Comment: Can't you just copy the Java file in place? I don't know your OS or IDE, but a copy-paste in your file OS explorer - or - a drag'n'drop from the OS file explorer to the IDE file explorer should do the trick.

Comment: Tutorial link is not working anymore.

Comment: Edited link, should work again

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Module in Android Studio you can choose which type on Module you want to create. Just choose `Android Library` and you will have access to the Android classes